# What is the TS type of a class extending another class?

Tags: typescript

```
const Err: ErrorConstructor = class Err extends Error {};
```

`ErrorConstructor` isn't correct here, but I'm not sure how to correctly define it.  Typescript isn't being helpful here and if I don't define the type it just says it's "typeof Err"

Note that this is a very condensed version of what I'm running into, I know I don't have to define it in this exact example but this is a minimal repro.

Comment: _'if I don't define the type it just says it's "typeof Err"'_ - Which is correct (and why do you declare a variable with the exact same name as the class `Err`?)

Comment: @Andreas -- Yes, the typeof the thing is the typeof the thing... Not helpful ;)  This is just an example, I'm just trying to figure out the type.  e.g. if I were to write `type mustExtendErrorClass = ....???`

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you want to do correctly, `ErrorConstructor` is a template that you want each of your `Error` derivatives to follow.

In such case, I would either derive a class `CustomError` from `Error`, and then derive the other `Err` classes from `CustomError`, or I would implement an interface `ICustomError` as well as extending directly from `Error`.

Say that you want all your `Err` types to give information about recoverability:

option 1: two levels of inheritance

```
class CustomError extends Error {
    constructor (
        public message: string,
        public recoverable: boolean
    ) {
        super();
        this.name = 'customError';
    }
}

class ErrA extends CustomError {

    constructor (
        public message: string,
        public recoverable: boolean
    ) {
        super(message, recoverable);
        this.name = 'ErrA';
    }
};
```

option 2: extends + implements

```
interface ICustomError {
    recoverable: boolean;
}

class ErrB extends Error implements ICustomError {
    constructor (
        public message: string,
        public recoverable: boolean
    ) {
        super();
        this.name = 'ErrB';
    }
};
```

Now what the type of `errA` and `errB` in the following? It's `ErrA` and `ErrB`, duh.

```
const errA = new ErrA('a', true);
const errB = new ErrB('b', true);
```

But since TS is a structural type system, you don't really care how they were constructed and you can use either of the following functions to display the message of both `errA` and `errB`

```
function displayCustomError(error: CustomError) {
    return error.message;
}

function displayCustomError2(error: Error & ICustomError) {
    return error.message;
}

function displayError(error: Error) {
    return error.message;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are getting `typeof Err` because classes are special values in TypeScript. Like `enums` they can be used as a type and as a value.

Consider next example:

```js
class A extends Error { }
class B extends Error { }

const a = (arg: A) => arg

a(new A()) // ok

a(A) // error

/////////////////////////////


const b = (arg: typeof A) => arg

b(new A()) // error

b(A) // ok
```

If you expect argument to be a type of class instance, use function `a` .

If you expect argument to be a type of class itself, use function `b`.

If you want to create `MustExtendsSomeClass`, I believe you can just use `typeof AnyClass`:

```js
class Animal {
    tag = 'animal'
}

class Dog extends Animal { }
class Cat extends Animal { }
class Ant { }

type MustExtendsAnimal = typeof Animal;

const e = <T extends MustExtendsAnimal>(error: T) => e

e(Dog) // ok
e(Cat) // ok
e(Ant) // error
```

As you might have noticed, `Ant` is unassignable and it is expected behaviour.

**But why it does not work with Error class ?**

```js
class A extends Error { }

type MustExtendsAnimal = typeof Error;

const e = <T extends MustExtendsAnimal>(error: T) => e

e(A) // error
```

Because it is built-in class with non standard type signature for classes:

```js
interface Error {
    name: string;
    message: string;
    stack?: string;
}

interface ErrorConstructor {
    new(message?: string): Error;
    (message?: string): Error;
    readonly prototype: Error;
}

declare var Error: ErrorConstructor;
```

It can be used with `new` keyword `new Error('custom error')` and as a regular function `Error(123)`

I'd willing to bet that this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68343186/how-to-implement-typescript-construct-signature-containing-both-constructor-and/68343681#68343681) is relative to our problem.
If you want to represent a class type which extends `Error` class, you should make sure that calling it without `new` will create `Error` class instance.

Smth like that:

```js
const Err = function (this: Error, message?: string) {
    if (new.target) {
        // If this function was called with new keyword
        this.message = message || ''
        this.name = 'some name'

        // some inheritance logic
    }
    // some inheritance logic
    return new Error('custom error')
}
```

But this function does not work either:

```js
const Err = function (this: Error, message?: string) {
    if (new.target) {
        // If this function was called with new keyword
        this.message = message || ''
        this.name = 'some name'

        // some inheritance logic
    }
    // some inheritance logic
    return new Error('custom error')
}

type MustExtendsAnimal = typeof Error;

const e = <T extends MustExtendsAnimal>(error: T) => e

e(Err) // error
```

because TS does not recognize this function as a constructor.

This is why you cant create such type for `Error` class.

I believe you can use this solution:

```js
type Overload<T extends InstanceType<typeof Error>> = ((this: Error, message?: string | undefined) => T) & { new(message?: string | undefined): T }

class A extends Error { }

const Err = A as Overload<A>

type MustExtendsAnimal = typeof Error;

const e = <T extends MustExtendsAnimal>(error: T) => e

e(Err) // error
```