# TypeScript - How should I write a function to match the type?

Tags: typescript

How should I write a function `fn` to match the type `DescribableFunction`

```
type DescribableFunction = {
    description: string;
    (arg: string): number;
    new (someArg: number): string
};
function doSomething(fn: DescribableFunction) {
    console.log(`${fn.description} returned ${fn('lorem')} or ${new fn(1)}`);
}

const fn: DescribableFunction = function (arg: string) {

}

doSomething(fn)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible without type assertions.

Due to historical reasons, some constructors in JavaScript can be invoked with `new` keyword or as a regular functions, for instance `Date` or `Array`.

These constructors are built in. You are not allowed to build such constructor without type assertions. However, you can get rid of `new (someArg: number): string` in `DescribableFunction` and just to add `description` property:

```js
type DescribableFunction = {
  description: string;
  (arg: string): number;
};

function doSomething(fn: DescribableFunction) {
  console.log(`${fn.description} returned ${fn('lorem')} or ${new fn(1)}`);
}

const fn: DescribableFunction = function (arg: string) {
  return 42
}
fn.description = ''

doSomething(fn)
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68643123/why-does-typescript-track-mutation-of-function-static-properties) you can find more explanation about typing static property of functions.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68343186/how-to-implement-typescript-construct-signature-containing-both-constructor-and/68343681#68343681) you can find related question/answer

P.S.Please keep in mind that you can create custom constructor with similar behavior in pure js (see [new.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new.target))

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I asked this question because I found similar construction in TypeScript documentation 
[link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html)
in Construct Signatures section
`
interface CallOrConstruct {
  new (s: string): Date;
  (n?: number): number;
}
`

Comment: You should use type assertion `as` to make it work in ts